# Different types of subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm studying about subqueries but I'm with some doubts about this topic. There are some types of subqueries? I already saw some sites that divide subqueries into "single-row subqueries, multiple column subqueries, multiple column subqueries". Others that say that are these types of subqueries "subquery as a new column, selecting data from a subquery, subqueries using multiple tables". So, Im, a bit confused about what are the types of subqueries that exist and how each type works. Do you know what types of subqueries exist and the difference between them? Or do you have any resource about this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call them different *types* of subquery... a subquery is just any query within another query. This can be applied in all sorts of different ways.

For example you might want a column that shows the (same) max range value for each row using a subquery which returns a single result:

```
SELECT ID, value
,(SELECT MAX(value) from TBL) AS MAX_VALUE
FROM TBL
```

Or you might JOIN to a subquery as if it were a table/ view eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN (
      SELECT B.col1, C.col2
      FROM B
      JOIN C on B.ID = C.ID
      WHERE B.col3 = 2
     ) SUB on A.col1 = SUB.col1
```

There are countless other ways to use a subquery - but essentially it's just any query to get your required result that sits within a larger query.

In terms of your examples - *any* query can be used to return a single row, or single value, or multiple columns - and may use one table, or multiple tables or indeed no tables. A subquery is no different - it just forms part of another query.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know some tutorial books or something to learn more about complex SQL queries, specifically for the select clause? Complex queries with joins, multiple tables, case statements, group by, subqueries.

Comment: That's kind of the basics of SQL... there are a lot of books and online resources, which suit different people. Try googling SQL tutorial or SQL for beginners and check out some of the options/ see what works for you.

Comment: Note that the second "type" is also referred to as a "derived table"

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of subqueries.  These depend on how the subqueries are used and how the subqueries are constructed.  Here are some examples.

One very important type is a *scalar subquery*.  This is a subquery that returns one column and at most one row.  A scalar subquery is important because it can be used anywhere -- or almost anywhere -- that a constant can be used.  So a scalar subquery can replace a constant such as `1` or `'abc'` or `current_date`.

(Note:  some databases relax the restriction on one column.)

In the `FROM` clause, subqueries return a *derived table*.  There is no restriction on the number of rows or columns returned.

Similarly, subqueries introduced with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` can return any number of rows and columns.

Then, there is `IN` and `NOT IN`.  Most databases require that these return only one column (but no restriction on the number of rows).  Some databases support multiple columns ("tuples") in this context.

Similarly -- although much less common -- subqueries can be used with comparison operations using `ANY`/`SOME`/`ALL`.  These also can only return one column (unless the database supports tuples).

Another use of "subqueries" is worth mentioning.  They can be used to define common table expressions (CTEs), introduced with `WITH`.

And subqueries are also used with lateral joins.

Finally, some subqueries refer to columns in the outer query.  These are *correlated subqueries*.  In general, they can be used anywhere except the `FROM` clause -- although lateral joins are an exception.

All of this should be covered in the documentation for the database that you are using.

Comment: Yes, the SQL standard does call it "derived table": "*A derived table is a table derived directly or indirectly from one or more other tables by the evaluation of a
<query expression>*"